# Get file names from azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, directory, azure-blob-storage, blob

I'm using azure blobstorage in c#, is there a way, a method to get the list of files from a given specific folder?
like get all file names inside this url https://prueba.blob.core.windows.net/simem/UAL/Dato%20de%20archivo%20prueba%20No1/2022/1/16
i know that using container.GetBlobs() i would get all files but not from a specific folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve blobs within a blob directory path using the Azure.Storage.Blobs BlobClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70778809/how-to-retrieve-blobs-within-a-blob-directory-path-using-the-azure-storage-blobs)

Answer (score 1):

You can get file names from a specific folder using `BlobServiceClient` and `GetBlobs` and by using below code in C# Console App and I followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient?view=azure-dotnet) and @[Cindy Pau](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67530352)'s answer:

```
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cs= "Connection String of Storage Account";
            string f = "test";
            BlobServiceClient b = new BlobServiceClient(cs);
            string c = "pool";
            BlobContainerClient containerClient =b.GetBlobContainerClient(c);
            var bs= containerClient.GetBlobs(prefix: f);
            foreach (var x in bs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

In Storage Account of **pool** Container:

[image]

Now inside **test** Folder:

[image]

**Output:**

Press Enter after every line to get File names one by one.

[image]

Comment: @Juan Castillo, have you got specific folder blob names as i have got?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
var results = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(prefix, true, BlobListingDetails.None, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: there is not a definition for that

Comment: Updated, looks like you are using the CloudBlobContainer

Comment: @JuanCastillo has this worked for you? Did you find another solution?